# Custom django signal not updating my models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to implement a custom signal but I have never done this before, so I seem to have messed this up.

Here is my code from models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import Signal
from django.db.models import Max,Count
from django.apps import apps

# Create your models here.
class Player(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    current_level_no = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    no_of_moves = models.IntegerField(null=True)    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Players'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.player_name

class PlayerStats(models.Model):
    player_name = models.ForeignKey(to=Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    level_no = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    moves = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Players Stats'

# It works!
TotalLevels = 25
MaxCurrentLevel = PlayerStats.objects.aggregate(max_levels=Max('level_no'))['max_levels']
PlayerCount = Player.objects.aggregate(count_players=Count('player_name', distinct=True))['count_players']


def create_player(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        new_username=instance.username
        Player.objects.create(player_name=new_username, current_level_no=None, no_of_moves=None)

def delete_player(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    deleted_username=instance.username
    Player.objects.filter(player_name=deleted_username).delete()

def create_player_stat(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for x in range(1, TotalLevels+1):
        PlayerStats.objects.create(player_name=instance, level_no=x, moves=None)

UpdateLevelsSignal = Signal(providing_args=['Update'])
if MaxCurrentLevel != TotalLevels and PlayerCount != 0:
    UpdateLevelsSignal.send(UpdateLevelsSignal,Update=True)

def UpdateLevels(sender, Update,**kwargs):
    if Update:
        if MaxCurrentLevel < TotalLevels:
            for x in Player.objects.all().values_list('player_name', flat=True):
                instance = Player.objects.get(player_name=x)
                for y in range(TotalLevels-MaxCurrentLevel, TotalLevels+1):
                    PlayerStats.objects.create(player_name=instance, level_no=y, moves=None)
        else:
            for x in Player.objects.all().values_list('player_name', flat=True):
                instance = Player.objects.get(player_name=x)
                for y in range(MaxCurrentLevel-TotalLevels, MaxCurrentLevel+1):
                    PlayerStats.objects.filter(player_name=instance, level_no=y, moves=None).delete()

post_save.connect(create_player, sender=User)
post_delete.connect(delete_player, sender=User)

post_save.connect(create_player_stat, sender=Player)

UpdateLevelsSignal.connect(UpdateLevels, sender=UpdateLevelsSignal)
```

Basically a signal to create or delete some model objects based on certain conditions, nothing too fancy. But, when I check on the model objects, there are no changes occurring on triggering the conditions.

If someone could point out what I am doing wrong here or suggest a solution, that would be helpful!

As always, I greatly appreciate your answers!

Comment: Is all of this code in the models.py file? Or do you have it broken up between a few files? If you have it broken up across a few files, it's likely that Django isn't actually registering the signals being connected. You can do that in the apps.py file.

Comment: @schillingt Its all in models.py so as to prevent the very problem you highlighted!

Comment: That's good for this particular situation, but once it's fixed you should consider moving things out into signals and receivers and wiring them up in apps. It cleans up your models file. Anyway, can you be more specific about what your test case is, what you expect to happen and what is happening? In `UpdateLevels` the only thing that would be triggered is `create_player_stat`, but I'm not sure if that's what you're expecting.

Comment: @schillingt I am actually interested in all of the stuff prefixed with Update, That is my custom django signal(the sender, reciever, etc) and yes I will take your advice into consideration, just would you mind explaining the reason a bit better for moving it into apps.py, I didn't quite understand that. I just wrote a loop to create more stats for new levels for each player when I increase the total no of levels and like wise did for deletion of stats for levels that have been deleted by decreasing the total no of levels. I wanted just automate these processes using django signals.

Comment: That makes sense, but you're not providing any specifics. For example, what is actually being created? Have you tried attaching a debugger and stepping through it or adding print statements before each line? When you encounter a bug in which you're at a loss for what's going on, you need to gather up as much information as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to solve your question, but I don't want to include it on a comment. The reason you should move your signals and receivers into their own files is limit how much business logic is in your models file. Plus it makes it more extensible when dealing with multiple apps.

```
project/
  app1/
     apps.py
     models.py
     signals.py
     receivers.py
  app2/
     apps.py
     models.py
     receivers.py
```

In each of the apps above,  the apps.py file would be something like:

```
class App1Config(AppConfig):

    def ready(self):
        # This makes Django load up the register the connected receivers.
        from project.app1 import receivers, signals
```

The reason you want to move the receivers into their own files is partly due to the case of wanting to trigger a function that only impacts models/objects in `app2`, but is triggered by some event on a model in `app1`. For example:

```
#project/app2/receivers.py

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from project.app1.models import Foo
from .models import Bar

@receiver(post_save, sender=Foo)
def create_bar_for_foo(instance, created, *, raw=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Bar.objects.create(foo=foo)
```

You could do that receiver in `app2/models.py`, but it would feel out of place. It would feel especially alien if it were a custom signal that has nothing to do with model-based events.

I wish the Django Documentation attempted to explain how to organize the signals and receivers, but the book Two Scoops of Django does a great job of explaining it.

Comment: I think I seem to have pissed you off, if I did, it wasn't meant to be. Thanks for the reasoning to move my signals to apps.py or a separate file. The reason, I couldn't give you particulars is because. I have not much idea about writing signals and writing this took me a lot of digging and understanding as best as I could on the django documentation, but I will try and use print statements as you suggested to narrow this down. Sorry for any inconvenience cause and thanks for the help till now.

Comment: Sorry that I came off that way. I didn't mean to.

Comment: Nah, I was just making sure I didn't ruin someone's day. Just something pre-cautionary!